# Going back to basics redux

Tags: javascript

I am trying to unblock my brain around something

I have the following code

```
const kategorierReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_KATEGORI':
            console.log(action.payload)
            return [state + {action.payload}]
        case 'LOAD_KATEGORI':
            return action.payload;
        case 'EDIT_KATEGORI':
            return action.payload;
        case 'DELETE_KATEGORI':
            return null;
        default:

            return state
    }
}
```

And my brain is blocked around the code in the case of 'ADD_KATEGORI', how to return the current state + the new object.

help?

Btw and offtopic, is it too hard to migrate to Apollo-GraphQL?

Comment: How you state looks like ?

Comment: @CodeManiac huge! but the KategorierReducer usually is a set of different objects like Kategories:{kategori1:{id1:1.a1:1}, kategori2:{id2:2.a2:2}}} and so on.

Comment: like `return {...state, ...action.payload}`?

Comment: something like `return {state: state, payload: action.payload}` ?

Comment: Thank you all. Has been a long night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return [state + {action.payload}]` should be `return {...state, ...action.payload}`

Comment: thanks! Sorry about the beginner question but it has been a long long night